# Jquery bind click and hover, how to check if click

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have combined function like this(simplified version):

```
$('label').bind('click hover', function() {
    $('label').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

How can I add an `if` to check if it is a click?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [`event.type`](http://api.jquery.com/event.type/):

```
$('label').bind('click hover', function(event) {
    if(event.type == 'click') {
        // do stuff
    }
    $('label').removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jtbowden/sqvDy/

Note, the demo uses `.on()`, which is the new method of event binding for jQuery 1.7+, replacing `.bind()`, `.live()`, and `.delegate()`.